# How do you correctly use @can in blade templates using policies

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not able to make the `@can()` in a blade template as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#via-blade-templates) suggest

Here's my policy:

```
public function update(User $user, Canal $canal): bool {
  return ($canal->user->id == $user->id) and ($user->hasPermissionTo('actualizar canal'));
}
```

I'm using Spatie Permissions. Anyway, this policy works, if I protect the routes in the controller as:

```
  public function edit(Request $request, Canal $canal) {
    $this->authorize('update', $canal);
    return view('Canal/edit', ['canal' => $canal]);
  }
```

Now, my problem is with the blade. I want to conditionally render a button to edit the `$canal`, I'm trying this:

```
  @can('update', App\Models\Canal::class)
    <x-gui.link-button href="{{ route('canal.edit', $canal->id) }}" value="Modificar" />
  @endcan
```

This is exactly as the docs say. But I'm getting an error, it says it needs another parameter in the call:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Policies\CanalPolicy::update()
```

So I'm guessing I have to send the user also in the `@can()`, I change it to:

```
  @can('update', Auth::user(), App\Models\Canal::class)
    <x-gui.link-button href="{{ route('canal.edit', $canal->id) }}" value="Modificar" />
  @endcan
```

This doesn't work either, this simply doesn't "call" the policy. How do I know? I placed some `Log::info()` there.

Any idea?

Comment: how does the @can method know _which_ canal ? you are passing the model not the instance.  How about `@can('update', $canal)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, send the `$code` instead of `App\Models\Canal::class` on the 2nd param of `@can` like:

```
@can('update', $canal)
    <x-gui.link-button href="{{ route('canal.edit', $canal->id) }}" value="Modificar" />
@endcan
```